# How can I visually represent the relationship between smoking, gender, age, and heart attack risk?

Tags: r, ggplot2, correlation, scatter-plot, gganimate

I have a database named AllDataset that contains the following data:
sex- (male, female)
smoke- (yes, no)
age- continuous variable
target- binary(0,1)
I check the relationship between smoking gender and age to the explained target variable using logistic regression. I performed the analysis and right now I need to find a representative graph.
I tried to use a scatter graph, but the values do not scatter from the box where the target variable is (suffered from a heart attack/does not suffer from a heart attack)
I would appreciate it if you could help me find a suitable graph

I tried to make a scatter graph but the data does not scatter for the reason that the target variable allows this, I am looking for a graph that will represent the relationship between the explanatory variables and the explained variable - the target

Comment: Consider an "interaction plot".  The y-axis is the predicted probability of your target variable, the x-axis is age, you facet the graph by sex and then have two lines on each facet, one for smokers and one for non-smokers.  If you provide a good enough sample of your dataset or a toy dataset we can demonstrate using R.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the reply,
I will add my dataset I wanted to check the relationship between heart attacks and smoking gender and age here.https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BSpcYg15BlomQT9WJCVOHhWr13kvdG82/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you add your dataset (or a sample of it) to the question text using (eg using `dput`).  See the top answer here on how to make a good minimal dataset for a question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Asking for advice on data visualization is on topic at [stats.se], not Stack Overflow. If you have a specific programming question, it's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. If you don't even know what output you want, get some plotting advice first.